# Fonts similiar to those in the ECMA-357 2nd standard?

Tags: font-identification, web-fonts

Are there fonts that match those used in the [ECMA-357 2nd edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-357_2nd_edition_december_2005.pdf) document?

Follows my attempts to discover the font:

- I have searched for ECMA-357 in the TC39 GitHub and found no matching repositories.
- I have tried opening it in LibreOffice and it converted the PDF by taking out the original font, so no luck there.
- I have tried an online service to detect the used font and it yielded *Arial Greek*. Arial Greek seems commercial. I'd like to know if there is a font in fonts.google.com that is close to the one in the document.

Screenshot:

[image: E4X]

Comment: If the font is in a PDF, you can open it in Acrobat and see a list of the fonts in it. That said, at first glance, it looks like Arial or Helvetica, though it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad You're right, under Document properties I was able to find a small number of fonts, and ArialMT was listed there.

Comment: Had a quick look, can confirm it's definitely Arial.  The characters:  t,1, and R are all dead giveaways for this font, and differentiate it from Helvetica.